# OOZIE Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie

I'm installing OOZIE 4.30 with Hadoop 2.9.1 and hive 1.2.2.
But when i do

`$ ooziedb.sh create -sqlfile oozie.sql -run`

i get

```
OOZIE Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI
```

Comment: Note: Hive 3.1.2 does not support Hadoop 2.7.7 ... Also not sure Oozie works with Hive3 at all

Comment: Thaks @OneCricketeer for your response. What do you think about working with hive 1.2.2 and oozie 5,2.0 and all with hadoop 2.9.1 ? Thanks

Comment: I think Hive 2.x would be best if working with Hadoop2. I havent installed oozie from scratch, so not sure which versioning is best for it

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. After building Oozie 5.2.0 which by default use hive 1.2.2, when i want to create the database for oozie meta data, i'm getting the following error : ./ooziedb.sh: line 77: /cygdrive/c/Java/jdk1.8.0_181/bin/java: Argument list too long

Comment: Guessing thats a problem with how Cygwin interprets your JAVA_HOME path

Comment: Yes it was the issue but now i put the oozie-tools-5.2.0.jar into libtools but i'm always getting the same error Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieDBCLI

Comment: Well, [that class does exist](https://github.com/apache/oozie/blob/release-5.2.0/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/oozie/tools/OozieDBCLI.java), so something with the [CLASSPATH setup in that shell script](https://github.com/apache/oozie/blob/release-5.2.0/distro/src/main/bin/oozie-setup.sh#L142-L143) is incorrect

Comment: I updated the oozie-setup.sh with the given below but now i'm facing the same isse with /ooziedb.sh create -sqlfile oozie.sql -run  commande